# Transactions from blockchain not confirmed for days

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

Please anybody in the house to help with this transaction

https://blockchain.info/tx/4ad6cccbd988248d1718909da6d98aaa3872594dfafc1aca7c52c3dbb7bd6ff4
It has been unconfirmed for days

Answer (score 0):

This transaction is not shown on any other block explorer I tried, namely Tradeblock and Blockcypher.

It has most likely been dropped or rejected.